# How to create a Foldable instance of a type with multiple parameters in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass, foldable

I have a data type:

```
data Box a b = Box a b
```

I want to create a `Foldable` instance of `Box` and since the `Foldable` instance has to be given something of kind `* -> *`, I'll declare the instance as:

```
instance Foldable (Box a) where
  foldr f x (Box r s) = undefined
```

Now I can only do something like:

```
foldr f x (Box r s) = f s x
```

in the definition of `foldr` but what if instead of operating on `s`, I want to to something like:

```
foldr f x (Box r s) = f r x
```

The compiler doesn't let me do this so what is the proper way to go about it?

Comment: @chi oops - thanks ... sadly it's to late to edit the thing and I don't know if it's of any worth ... so I guess I'll remove it

Comment: The proper way?  Some options. 1. Do not use `Foldable` because you want something that is semantically different. 2. Make `type B a = Box a a ; instance Foldable B where` then fold over both elements.  3. Make an instance for a newtype wrapper `newtype FlipBox a b = FBox (Box b a) ; instance Foldable (FlipBox a) where ...`.

Comment: @ThomasMDuBuisson, you can't make a type synonym an instance of a class.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes you can. Relax. :)

Comment: In general you can use `TypeSynonymInstances` but that fails in this case since they must be fully saturated for instance declarations, and hence you can't make `B` itself an instance of anything only `B a` for some `a`, and that defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already figured out the answer -- you just don't like it. There's no way to do what you're asking, since the only possible behavior is fixed by the signature of `foldr`.

The suggestion of a newtype `newtype Flip t a b = Flip {unFlip :: (t b a)}` with an appropriate instance defined is the most standard way to work around this, and now you can write your fold on a `Flip Box` instead of on a `Box`.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the instance as: instance Foldable Box where ...
(Box a):: *